# A handler that runs every 5 minutes runs in duplicate

Tags: android, video, android-handler

My handler will record the camera screen every 5 minutes

recently, I found handler runs in duplicate.

handler is before record the camera screen, create record file name.

if normal, 15:00:00.mp4 , 15:05:00.mp4, 15:10:00.mp4.

but current my state is 15:00:00.mp4, 15:02:15.mp4, 15:05:00.mp4, 15:07:15.mp4.

It seems that the same handler is duplicated and the 2 are executed.

so, I want if there is a handler already working, delete the old handler, execute new handler.

then, I think solve same handler duplicate problem. is right?

to sum it up, 
1. Before doing `handler.sendEmptyMessage`, Is it possible to check if the same handler is working?.

2. if 1 is possible, How to delete a running handler and run only the new handler.

current my source.

```
private RecHandler mHandler = new RecHandler(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(REQUEST_HANDLE_INIT_RECORD);
}
```

RecHandler.class

```
public class RecHandler extends Handler {

   private final SoftReference<MainActivity> weak;
    public RecHandler(MainActivity act) {
       weak = new SoftReference<BlackEyeActivity>(act);
    }
       @Override
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
           MainActivity act = weak.get();
           RecHandler mHandler = new RecHandler(act);

           if (act != null) {
               switch (msg.what) {
                    case REQUEST_HANDLE_INIT_RECORD:
                        initCapturing(); //init camera preview..

                        mHandler = new RecHandler(act);
                        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(REQUEST_HANDLE_START_RECORD, 1000); //after 1 second, start REQUEST_HANDLE_START_RECORD.
                        this.removeMessages(REQUEST_HANDLE_HOLD_RECORD);
                        break;

                    case REQUEST_HANDLE_START_RECORD :
                         startRecording(); //start Recording.. record file 5 minute.
                         mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(REQUEST_HANDLE_HOLD_RECORD, 300000); //after 5 minute, start REQUEST_HANDLE_HOLD_RECORD.
                         this.removeMessages(REQUEST_HANDLE_INIT_RECORD);
                         break;

                    case REQUEST_HANDLE_HOLD_RECORD:
                         stopRecording();

                         mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(REQUEST_HANDLE_INIT_RECORD, 1000); //after 1 second, start REQUEST_HANDLE_INIT_RECORD.
                         this.removeMessages(REQUEST_HANDLE_START_RECORD);
                         break;
```

so, My handler if always record, repeat `INIT`(1 seconds) -> `START` (5 minute) -> `HOLD`(1 seconds)

if you know how to check if the same handler is working, and how to delete a running handler and run only the new handler. please advice for me.

Comment: inside `onDestroy` call `mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`

Comment: @pskink thanks. is it possible when I use `removeCallbacksAndMessages`   prevent duplicate handlers?